# StatefulSet is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than .. 'persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy' are forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, eventstoredb

I am trying to deploy, to a Kubernetes cluster hosted on Azure (AKS v1.26.6), the following configurations: `statefulset.yml` and `storageclass.yml`.

**storageclass.yml**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: managed-premium-retain
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
reclaimPolicy: Retain
parameters:
  storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS
```

**statefulset.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eventstore-cluster
  labels:
    app: eventstore-cluster
spec:
  clusterIP: "None"
  ports:
  - port: 2113
    name: eventstore-web
  - port: 1113
    name: eventstore-tcp
  - port: 2112
    name: gossip
  selector:
    app: eventstore-cluster
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: eventstore-cluster
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eventstore-cluster 
  serviceName: eventstore-cluster
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eventstore-cluster 
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - eventstore-cluster
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: eventstore
        image: eventstore/eventstore:release-4.1.1-hotfix1
        env:
        - name: EVENTSTORE_CLUSTER_SIZE 
          value: "3"
        - name: EVENTSTORE_DISCOVER_VIA_DNS
          value: "true"
        - name: EVENTSTORE_CLUSTER_DNS 
          value: "eventstore-cluster"
        - name: EVENTSTORE_EXT_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 2113
          name: eventstore-web
        - containerPort: 1113
          name: eventstore-tcp
        - containerPort: 2112
          name: gossip
        volumeMounts:
        - name: eventstore-cluster-data
          mountPath: /var/lib/eventstore
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 2113
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 15
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 2113
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: eventstore-cluster-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "managed-premium-retain"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
```

When I run the command:

```
kubectl apply -f .\statefulSet.yml
```

The following error is shown:

> The StatefulSet "eventstore-cluster" is
> invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other
> than 'replicas', 'ordinals', 'template', 'updateStrategy',
> 'persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy' and 'minReadySeconds' are
> forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Oh no.. after a failed deployment of the `statefulset`, it turns out when I was running the command:

```
kubectl apply -f .\statefulSet.yml
```

The error was being shown as the statefulset was already there.

Running the following command showed all running stateful sets:

```
kubectl get statefulsets
```

> NAME                 READY   AGE eventstore-cluster   0/3     6h1m

Finally, running the command to delete the broken statefulset fixed the issue for me:

```
kubectl delete statefulsets eventstore-cluster
```